# ResourceAware Implementation in ItemProcessor returns resource as Null

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I know the question i am asking have been asked may times here. But even after referring those answers my problem is not yet solved.So i am posting it again

I need to read the name of the resource currently being processed in ItemProcessor. For that i am trying to use **ResourceAware** marker Interface which have the setResource Method which we need to implement. As per my reading if we are using MultiResourceItemReader the ResourceAware`s setResourceMethod should be called and thus we can get the reference to the current item which is processed. But for some reason this is not happening. Please find my below configurations

```
<step id="readChatLogsData">
<tasklet>
    <chunk reader="multiResourceReader" processor="chatProcessor" writer="mongodbItemWriter" commit-interval="100">
    </chunk>
</tasklet>
</step>

<beans:bean id="multiResourceReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader" scope="step">
    <beans:property name="resources" value="file:*.log" />
    <beans:property name="delegate" ref="chatReader" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="chatReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <beans:property name="lineMapper" ref="tickerLineMapper" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="tickerLineMapper"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
    <beans:property name="fieldSetMapper" ref="chatMapper" />
    <beans:property name="lineTokenizer" ref="tickerLineTokenizer" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="tickerLineTokenizer"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
    <beans:property name="delimiter" value="^A" />
    <beans:property name="names" value="A,B,C" />
</beans:bean>

public class ChatProcessor  implements ItemProcessor<SingleChatFileInput,String>, ResourceAware
```

Please let me know if i am doing something wrong here or i am missing anythings.
Also please suggest if there is any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Marker interface indicating that an item should have the Spring
>   Resource in which it was read from, set on it.

`ResourceAware` interface should be implemented by object returned from `chatReader` (I think `SingleChatFileInput`), not by `ItemProcessor`.

Comment: Worked like a Charm :). Thanks a lot Luca.